# I am new to python and this error keeps showing up

Tags: python

the error :

```
traceback (most recent call last):   file "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    states_in_india [0] = "Rajastan" typeerror : 'tuiple' object does not support item assignment
```

the code :

```
states_in_india = "Maharashtra","Gujrat","Punjab"

print(states_in_india)

states_in_india[0] = "Rajastan"

states_in_india.extend = "Tamilnadu"

print (states_in_india)
```

Comment: you are defining states_of_india as a tuple, which doesn't allow item assignment, better use lists like `states_in_india = ["Maharashtra","Gujrat","Punjab"]`

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, and don't attempt to format it by hand.

Comment: Please invest time in learning list, tuple and set in python.

Comment: 1) `states_in_india` is a tuple; 2) `states_in_india[0] = "Rajastan"` attempts to assign a different value to its first element; 3) Tuples are immutable, so it's not possible to do this. Also, `states_in_india.extend = "Tamilnadu"` is not how one appends elements to a tuple. In fact, it's not possible to append elements to tuples - use lists instead

Comment: tuples are immutable. You can use list instead. Also `states_in_india.extend = "Tamilnadu"` will result in another error.  If you use list you can use `append()` method for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples are immutable and so you cannot mutate them by assigning values to one of their indexes.

You probably want to use a list.

```py
states_in_india = "Maharashtra","Gujrat","Punjab"
states_in_india[0] = "whatever" #illegal
```

```py
states_in_india = ["Maharashtra","Gujrat","Punjab"]
states_in_india[0] = "whatever" #legal, changes the list
states_in_india
>>> ["whatever","Gujrat","Punjab"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
states_in_india = "Maharashtra","Gujrat","Punjab" # this is tuple

print(states_in_india)
# below line is illegal in tuple cause you can't add, remove from tuple 
states_in_india[0] = "Rajastan"
```

Convert your code to list

```
    states_in_india = ["Maharashtra","Gujrat","Punjab"]
```

add [] in your code will declare as a list

```
states_in_india[0] = "Rajastan"
```

this code will work prefectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).